# Retrieving Intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

This is my set up.

Fragment F1 hosted by Activity A1.

Fragment F2 hosted by Activity A2.

F1 calls A2 via startActivity() and passes an extra (which is a static member variable (a key like structure) present in F2).

If the intent extra goes directly to the static member variable of F2 via startActivity(), then why do we have to use `getActivity().getIntent().get___extra()` to get the intent extra ?

Example :

F1 (ListFragment.class)

A1 (ListActivity.class)

F2 (DetailFragment.class).This has a static member KEY which is a string.

A2 (DetailActivity.class)

Sequence :

```
// In ListFragment.class
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class)
i.putExtra(F2.KEY,'xxx');
i.startActivity();


//In DetailFragment.class
String s = getActivity().getIntent.getStringExtra(KEY); --Statement 1
```

Instead of statement 1, why can't I directly access KEY data because I assume that the startActivity() would have put the data in this static member..Is this assumption not right ?

Comment: "f the intent extra goes directly to the static member variable of F2 via startActivity()" ? How is that happening?

Comment: `xxx` doesn't `goes into KEY`, it goes into a map, you can choose to see it as a `hashmap`, where it consists of keys and values, that is how you get data out from `getIntent()`, you get a value out from map, using a key identifier.